# A Tor-enabled daytime client

Tags: c, networking

The following is a daytime client written in C that uses Tor to connect to a given daytime server. It assumes a Tor daemon is running on the system and that Tor can be reached via a specified UNIX domain socket. This uses the SOCKS5 protocol to talk to Tor, and then uses the daytime protocol to display the current date and time.

I desire for this to be portable to any system conforming to the Single UNIX Standard and which has C11 conformance; please point out any extensions which are used. I adhere to the standards very, very closely.

Some things that can be improved/changed that I'm aware of:

Use `mbsrtowcs` instead of `mbstowcs` so we don't have to rely on XSI conformance, and adding help text. Also, supporting socket pathnames longer than can fit in the structure by (on systems that support it) allocating an oversize `struct sockaddr_un`

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 201112L
#error A C11-conforming compiler is required
/* This is because we use UTF-8 string literals to ensure text is encoded in ASCII. */
#endif
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
/* We rely on the XSI extension to mbstowcs(). */
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#if !defined(_POSIX_IPV6) || _POSIX_IPV6 == -1
#pragma GCC warning "Build-time IPv6 support is required"
#endif

/* Note that, when we talk to the Tor daemon, we use assertions to validate
 * that it's conforming to the SOCKS protocol and giving the expected responses.
 * This is normally inappropriate from a networking point of view, but a Tor
 * daemon on the running system is supposed to be trusted. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[static argc+1]) {
    if(!setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) {
        fputs("Failed to enable default locale\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const bool onion_opt_works = getopt(2, (char*[]){"a.out", "-", NULL}, "") == L'';
    optind = 1;

    const char *sockpath = NULL;
    int opt;
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, onion_opt_works ? "s::" : "s:")) != -1) {
        if(opt == '?') {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        assert(opt == 's' || (onion_opt_works && opt == L''));
        if(sockpath) {
            fputs("The Tor socket to use may be specified only once.\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sockpath = optarg;
    }

    if(!sockpath) {
        /* This educated guess is based on the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. */
        sockpath = "/run/tor/socks";
    }

    char *const hostname = argv[optind] ? argv[optind] : "time.nist.gov";

    /* In case we disconnect from Tor for whatever reason,
     * we don't want the default action of SIGPIPE. */
    if(signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Failed to change disposition of SIGPIPE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const struct servent *const daytime = getservbyname("daytime", "tcp");
    if(!daytime) {
        fputs("Failed to get information on daytime service\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Instead of using a TCP connection to Tor, since the Tor
     * daemon should be running on this same system anyway, we're
     * going to talk to it over a UNIX domain socket. */
    union {
        struct sockaddr_un sun_addr;
        struct sockaddr sa_addr;
    } addr = { .sun_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX };
    const size_t sockpathlen = strlen(sockpath);
    if(sizeof(addr.sun_addr.sun_path) < sockpathlen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to socket: %s\n", strerror(ENAMETOOLONG));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(addr.sun_addr.sun_path, sockpath, sockpathlen);

    const int sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(connect(sock, &addr.sa_addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to %s: %s\n", addr.sun_addr.sun_path, strerror(errno));
        if(close(sock) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to close socket");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Instead of having to call read() and write() in loops every
     * time to ensure complete data transfer, we're going to turn
     * our socket into two streams so we can use the semantics of
     * fread() and fwrite(). Being able to use getdelim() to read
     * the data will also prove useful later on. */
    FILE *const readstream = fdopen(sock, "r");
    if(!readstream) {
        perror("Failed to create stream");
        if(close(sock) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to close socket");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const int dupsock = dup(sock);
    if(dupsock == -1) {
        perror("Failed to duplicate file descriptor");
        goto endreadstream;
    }

    FILE *const writestream = fdopen(dupsock, "w");
    if(!writestream) {
        perror("Failed to create stream");
        if(close(dupsock) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to close socket");
        }
        goto endreadstream;
    }
    /* We need writes to go out immediately, but there's not really
     * any problem with our read stream being buffered. */
    if(setvbuf(writestream, NULL, _IONBF, 0)) {
        fputs("Failed to disable buffering on stream\n", stderr);
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    /* Specify that we're using SOCKS5 and we support just one
     * authentication method, which is none at all. Tor shouldn't
     * need authentication. */
    if(!fwrite(&(struct {uint8_t version; uint8_t nmethods; uint8_t methods;}){0x05, 0x01, 0x00}, 3, 1, writestream)) {
        perror("Failed to start client handshake");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    struct {
        uint8_t version;
        uint8_t method;
    } servmsg;
    /* The socket underlying the read stream is not a non-blocking
     * one, so if we reach end of file then we've lost our connection
     * to the Tor daemon. */
    if(!fread(&servmsg, sizeof(servmsg), 1, readstream)) {
        if(feof(readstream)) {
            errno = ENOTCONN;
        }
        perror("Failed to read server handshake");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    if(servmsg.version != 0x05) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Tor is using unexpected SOCKS version %"PRIu8 "\n", servmsg.version);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if(servmsg.method == 0xFF) {
        fputs("Unable to complete Tor daemon", stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to complete Tor daemon handshake: %s\n",
            #ifdef ENEEDAUTH
            strerror(ENEEDAUTH)
            #else
            strerror(EPERM)
            #endif
        );
        goto endwritestream;
    } else {
        assert(servmsg.method == 0x00);
    }

    const iconv_t toascii = iconv_open("US-ASCII", nl_langinfo(CODESET));
    if(toascii == (iconv_t)-1) {
        perror("Failed to get codeset conversion descriptor");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    /* Here we use mbstowcs() to count characters, but not because
     * we're converting to wide characters. We're converting to ASCII. */
    const size_t hostnameasciilen = mbstowcs(NULL, hostname, 0);
    if(hostnameasciilen == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("Failed to count characters");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    char *const asciihostname = calloc(hostnameasciilen + 1, 1);
    if(!asciihostname) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory for hostname string");
        if(iconv_close(toascii) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to close codeset conversion descriptor");
        }
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    if(iconv(toascii, &(char*){hostname}, &(size_t){strlen(hostname)}, &(char*){asciihostname}, &(size_t){hostnameasciilen}) == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("Failed to convert between codesets");
        if(iconv_close(toascii) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to close codeset conversion descriptor");
        }
        free(asciihostname);
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    if(iconv_close(toascii) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to close codeset conversion descriptor");
        free(asciihostname);
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    if(!fwrite(&(struct {
            uint8_t version;
            uint8_t command;
            uint8_t reserved;
            uint8_t addrtype;
            uint8_t domainlen;
            /* TODO: Instead of calling strlen(), we can recycle info from the iconv() call. */
            }){5, 1 /* connect */, 0, 3 /* domain name */, strlen(asciihostname)},
        5, 1, writestream) || !fwrite(asciihostname, strlen(asciihostname), 1, writestream)) {
        perror("Failed to write");
        free(asciihostname);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    free(asciihostname);

    if(!fwrite(&(uint16_t){daytime->s_port}, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, writestream)) {
        perror("Failed to write");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    struct {
        uint8_t version;
        uint8_t replytype;
        uint8_t reserved;
        uint8_t addresstype;
    } recv1;
    if(!fread(&recv1, sizeof(recv1), 1, readstream)) {
        if(feof(readstream)) {
            errno = ENOTCONN;
        }
        perror("Failed to receive server reply message");
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    assert(recv1.version == 5);

    #define SOCKSPERROR(reply, errnum) case reply: fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errnum)); goto endwritestream;
    switch(recv1.replytype) {
    case 0:
        break;
    SOCKSPERROR(2, EPERM);
    SOCKSPERROR(3, ENETUNREACH);
    SOCKSPERROR(4, EHOSTUNREACH);
    SOCKSPERROR(5, ECONNREFUSED);
    SOCKSPERROR(6, ETIMEDOUT);
    SOCKSPERROR(7, EOPNOTSUPP);
    SOCKSPERROR(8, EAFNOSUPPORT);
    default:
        fputs("Unknown error\n", stderr);
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    uint8_t addrlen;
    switch(recv1.addresstype) {
    case 1: /* IPv4 */
        addrlen = sizeof(struct in_addr);
        break;
    case 4: /* IPv6 */
        addrlen = sizeof(struct in6_addr);
        break;
    case 3: /* domain name */
        if(!fread(&addrlen, sizeof(addrlen), 1, readstream)) {
            if(feof(readstream)) {
                errno = ENOTCONN;
            }
            perror("Failed to get domain name length");
            goto endwritestream;
        }
        break;
    default:
        abort();
    }

    assert(addrlen > 0);
    /* We retrieve the canonical address the SOCKS server can be
     * reached at, but we actually don't care about it; we read it
     * only so we can move past it. We're perfectly content talking
     * to Tor over the UNIX domain socket. */
    void *const canonaddr = malloc(addrlen);
    if(!canonaddr) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if(!fread(canonaddr, addrlen, 1, readstream)) {
        if(feof(readstream)) {
            errno = ENOTCONN;
        }
        perror("Failed to receive address");
        free(canonaddr);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    free(canonaddr);

    if(!fread(&(uint16_t){0}, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, readstream)) {
        perror("Failed to receive port");
        goto endwritestream;
    }

    char *time;
reread:
    time = NULL;
    getdelim(&time, &(size_t){0}, u8"\n"[0], readstream);
    if(ferror(readstream)) {
        perror("Failed to read time");
        free(time);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if(feof(readstream)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(ENOTCONN));
        free(time);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if(time[0] == u8"\n"[0]) {
        /* NIST's server always starts with a blank line for some odd reason. */
        free(time);
        goto reread;
    }
    if(fclose(writestream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close stream");
        free(time);
        goto endreadstream;
    }
    if(fclose(readstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close stream");
        free(time);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Convert the string from ASCII to the locale's encoding. */
    char *localetime = calloc(MB_CUR_MAX, strlen(time) + 1);
    if(!localetime) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        free(time);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const iconv_t conv = iconv_open(nl_langinfo(CODESET), "US-ASCII");
    if(conv == (iconv_t)-1) {
        perror("Failed to get codeset conversion descriptor");
        free(time);
        free(localetime);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(iconv(conv, &(char*){time}, &(size_t){strlen(time)}, &(char*){localetime}, &(size_t){MB_CUR_MAX * strlen(time)}) == (size_t)-1) {
        perror("Failed to convert string to the locale's encoding");
        free(time);
        free(localetime);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(iconv_close(conv) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to close codeset conversion descriptor");
        free(time);
        free(localetime);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(time);

    if(fputs(localetime, stdout) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to print message");
        free(localetime);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(localetime);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

endwritestream:
    if(fclose(writestream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close stream");
    }
endreadstream:
    if(fclose(readstream) == EOF) {
        perror("Failed to close stream");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## General Observations

Because this code needs to be POSIX compliant there are very few Linux systems that can officially run this. Only [two versions of Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) are officially compliant with POSIX. Targeting SUS Unix is not really portable.

I would consider this code to be [Spaghetti Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) (This term has been around since at least the 1980s and it is not a good label). Because of the complexity of the code, the number of labels declared and the number of `goto` statements I originally thought this code was using `goto` statements instead of function calls.

## Don't Call `exit()` From `main()`

In C programming there is no need to call the `exit(STATUS)` from `main()`; any `return` from main provides the same functionality. While no compiler will flag this function call, it is logically incorrect and unnecessary. The `exit()` function was created for one purpose and that is to `exit()` the program from any function that isn't `main()`. Since there is no `abort` handler in this code there is really no reason to call `abort()`.

## Complexity

In this code there is only one function, and that is the `main()` function. The `main()` function is currently 362 lines long. A common best practice in coding is that no function should be larger than one screen in an IDE or editor. This is because it is very hard to follow logic in a function that is larger than one screen (requires scrolling up and down). I would consider the code in this program to be impossible to maintain. This is a problem because there are always bugs in code - and how would one add new features to the code?

The function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

While this principle was originally written for object-oriented code this also applies to procedural code.

Most of the `goto` statements could be removed if this code was properly written with functions.

## Don't Use `goto` to Loop

The `reread:` label and the `goto reread;` statement are unnecessary in this code, you can use a `do {} while` loop instead.

```
    char* time;
reread:
    time = NULL;
    getdelim(&time, &(size_t){0}, u8"\n"[0], readstream);
    if (ferror(readstream)) {
        perror("Failed to read time");
        free(time);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if (feof(readstream)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(ENOTCONN));
        free(time);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
    if (time[0] == u8"\n"[0]) {
        /* NIST's server always starts with a blank line for some odd reason. */
        free(time);
        goto reread;
    }
```

All of above code should be in a function that returns a status indicating success or failure.

## Assert Statements

In the C programming language `assert()` is a macro; if the code is compiled in any mode except debug the `assert()` is optimized out of the code.

## Don't Hide `goto` in Macros

This `switch` statement can be simplified:

```
#define SOCKSPERROR(reply, errnum) case reply: fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errnum)); goto endwritestream;
    switch (recv1.replytype) {
    case 0:
        break;
        SOCKSPERROR(2, EPERM);
        SOCKSPERROR(3, ENETUNREACH);
        SOCKSPERROR(4, EHOSTUNREACH);
        SOCKSPERROR(5, ECONNREFUSED);
        SOCKSPERROR(6, ETIMEDOUT);
        SOCKSPERROR(7, EOPNOTSUPP);
        SOCKSPERROR(8, EAFNOSUPPORT);
    default:
        fputs("Unknown error\n", stderr);
        goto endwritestream;
    }
```

to the following code which removes the need for the macro hiding the `goto`.

```
    unsigned int error_numbers[] =
    {
        0, 0, EPERM, ENETUNREACH, EHOSTUNREACH, ECONNREFUSED, ETIMEDOUT, EOPNOTSUPP, EAFNOSUPPORT
    };


    if (recv1.replytype)
    {
        if (recv1.replytype < 2 || recv1.replytype > 8)
        {
            fputs("Unknown error\n", stderr);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(recv1.replytype));
        }
        goto endwritestream;
    }
```

The code is also easier to maintain.

## Magic Numbers

There are Magic Numbers in the `main()` function (0, 2 through 8 above). It might be better to create symbolic constants for them to make the code more readable and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintenance easier.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882).

In some cases these numbers may be defined as symbolic constants in header files already in use.